# System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run error

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have an application running and when I close it, it generates an error.

So the Form application is ran

```
[STAThread]
public void Main()
{       
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());  
}
```

When I close application Form1, my IDE throws the following error:

```
SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.
```

How do I make the rest of the application run, without generating the SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault error once I close the form?

Update:
I'm reading that it could be because the application is still running, (the instance)

is there an equivalent of:

```
sForm.Close()
```

I should be using?

Comment: What does *make the rest of the application run* mean? That's your `Program.cs` file of the Solution's starting Project, right? Or, do you have `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` (or Application.Run) somewhere else? Can you show your Solution's structure?

Comment: I think this is likely a threading error somewhere in the app.  You'll have to share more about what you've done in the code.  Do you have Timers or Networking code or Threads of any kind?  What about static constructors?

Comment: I'm still new to coding. This was created in visual stuidio, but I have renamed some methods and had to modfiy some class modifiers to make it work in a third party app with its own IDE. It is working perfectly when Form1 is running, but when I close the application, that's when I get the error.

Comment: Update: Based on your questions, I was able to fix the issue.
Issue was solved because my method calls the application multiple times. I added logic so it only does it once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My method calls itself based on events. Multiple events happening when the application is already loaded caused the issue. 
I placed a simple conditional to run once, and problem solved.